# Compute each box arising from intersecting a rectangle with [0, 1)^d, where the latter is considered with wrap arround

Tags: c++, math, geometry, computational-geometry

Consider the box [0, 1)^d with wrap arround; for example, `1 + .05 = .05` in each dimension.

Given a point `x` inside [0, 1)^d and a positive constant `epsilon` (between 0 and .5), I want to obtain a vector of all "boxes" inside [0, 1)^d which arise by wrapping around the box with minimum corner `x - (epsilon, ..., epsilon)` and maximum corner `x + (epsilon, ..., epsilon)`.

I think a picture helps a lot; here is the case `d = 2`:

[image]

Here we've got 9 cases. The small black rectangle is the one spanned by `x` and `epsilon`; the red ones are the boxes arising from the wrap around.

I can code this as follows (I'm using the box model from boost, but that's not important):

```
template<typename T>
void foo(point<T, 2> const& x, T const& epsilon)
{
    assert(0 < epsilon && epsilon < T(1) / 2);

    std::array<boost::geometry::model::box<point<double, 2>>, 4> boxes;
    std::size_t box_count{};

    if (x[0] - epsilon < 0)
    {
        if (x[1] - epsilon < 0)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, T{});
            boxes[0].max_corner() = x + make_point(epsilon, epsilon);

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(1 + x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon);

            boxes[2].min_corner() = x + make_point(1 - epsilon, 1 - epsilon);
            boxes[2].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), T(1));

            boxes[3].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, 1 + x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[3].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, T(1));

            box_count = 4;
        }
        else if (x[1] + epsilon >= 1)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, T(1));

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, T{});
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, x[1] + epsilon - 1);

            boxes[2].min_corner() = make_point(1 + x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[2].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon - 1);

            boxes[3].min_corner() = make_point(1 + x[0] - epsilon, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[3].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), T(1));

            box_count = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, x[1] + epsilon);

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(1 + x[0] - epsilon, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon);

            rbox_count = 2;
        }
    }
    else if (x[0] + epsilon >= 1)
    {
        if (x[1] - epsilon < 0)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon);

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, 1 + x[0] - epsilon);
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), T(1));

            boxes[2].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, 1 + x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[2].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon - 1, T(1));

            boxes[3].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, T{});
            boxes[3].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon - 1, x[1] + epsilon);

            box_count = 4;
        }
        else if (x[1] + epsilon >= 1)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = x - make_point(epsilon, epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), T(1));

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon - 1, T(1));

            boxes[2].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, T{});
            boxes[2].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon - 1, x[1] + epsilon - 1);

            boxes[3].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[3].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon - 1);

            box_count = 4;
        }
        else
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = x - make_point(epsilon, epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(T(1), x[1] + epsilon);

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(T{}, x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon - 1, x[1] + epsilon);

            box_count = 2;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (x[1] - epsilon < 0)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[0].max_corner() = x + make_point(epsilon, epsilon);

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, 1 + x[1] - epsilon);
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, T(1));

            box_count = 2;
        }
        else if (x[1] + epsilon >= 1)
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = x - make_point(epsilon, epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, T(1));

            boxes[1].min_corner() = make_point(x[0] - epsilon, T{});
            boxes[1].max_corner() = make_point(x[0] + epsilon, 1 - x[1] + epsilon);

            box_count = 2;
        }
        else
        {
            boxes[0].min_corner() = x - make_point(epsilon, epsilon);
            boxes[0].max_corner() = x + make_point(epsilon, epsilon);

            box_count = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is quite complicated. I've considered each case separately. My question is: How can we simplify this such that it works for arbitrary dimension `d`?

Comment: you probably want to use `std::fmod`

Comment: You may also want to consider posting the theoretical part of this problem over on https://math.stackexchange.com especially if you're trying to solve this for arbitrary dimensions: higher dimensions start doing really funky things. And if you're _not_ going to run this code for anything except for `d=2` then please update your post and explicitly frame this as a 2D problem, because that drastically changes what the solution looks like.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your suggestions. I really need arbitrary dimension `d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that each dimension would separately change the number of boxes by a factor of either 1 or 2. So, inductively, you might have the following. (I have tried to replicate something like your nine 2-d testcases and added one 3-d testcase with maximum split.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Box
{
   vector<pair<double,double>> bounds;
};

ostream & operator << ( ostream &out, const Box &box )
{
   out << "Box:  ";
   for ( int i = 0; i < box.bounds.size(); i++ ) out << box.bounds[i].first << " < x" << i + 1 << " < " << box.bounds[i].second << "      ";
   return out;
}

//======================================================================

vector<Box> makeBoxes( const vector<double> &x, double eps )      // x is multidimensional centre, eps is half-width
{
   vector<Box> boxes(1);

   // Do the wraparound for each dimension in turn
   for ( int d = 0; d < x.size(); d++ )
   {
      vector<Box> newboxes;
      double lower = x[d] - eps, higher = x[d] + eps;
      for ( Box b : boxes )
      {
         auto b1 = b, b2 = b;
         if ( lower < 0 )
         {
            b1.bounds.push_back( { 1.0 + lower, 1.0    } );   newboxes.push_back( b1 );
            b2.bounds.push_back( { 0.0        , higher } );   newboxes.push_back( b2 );
         }
         else if ( higher > 1.0 )
         {
            b1.bounds.push_back( { lower, 1.0          } );   newboxes.push_back( b1 );
            b2.bounds.push_back( { 0.0  , higher - 1.0 } );   newboxes.push_back( b2 );
         }
         else
         {
            b1.bounds.push_back( { lower, higher } );   newboxes.push_back( b1 );
         }
      }
      boxes = newboxes;
   }

   return boxes;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   vector<vector<double>> testcases2d = {
      { 0.1, 0.1 },
      { 0.1, 0.9 },
      { 0.1, 0.5 },
      { 0.9, 0.1 },
      { 0.9, 0.9 },
      { 0.9, 0.5 },
      { 0.5, 0.1 },
      { 0.5, 0.9 },
      { 0.5, 0.5 }
                                        };
   double eps = 0.2;

   for ( int i = 0; i < testcases2d.size(); i++ )
   {
      cout << "2D Testcase " << i + 1 << '\n';
      vector<Box> box2d = makeBoxes( testcases2d[i], eps );
      for ( Box b : box2d ) cout << b << '\n';
      cout << "\n\n";
   }


   vector<double> testcase3d = { 0.9, 0.9, 0.9 };
   cout << "3D Testcase (corner): \n";
   vector<Box> box3d = makeBoxes( testcase3d, eps );
   for ( Box b : box3d ) cout << b << '\n';
}
```

```
2D Testcase 1
Box:  0.9 < x1 < 1      0.9 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.9 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.3      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.3      0.9 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.3      0 < x2 < 0.3      


2D Testcase 2
Box:  0.9 < x1 < 1      0.7 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.9 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.3      0.7 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.3      0 < x2 < 0.1      


2D Testcase 3
Box:  0.9 < x1 < 1      0.3 < x2 < 0.7      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.3      0.3 < x2 < 0.7      


2D Testcase 4
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0.9 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.3      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0.9 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0 < x2 < 0.3      


2D Testcase 5
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0.7 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0.7 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0 < x2 < 0.1      


2D Testcase 6
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0.3 < x2 < 0.7      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0.3 < x2 < 0.7      


2D Testcase 7
Box:  0.3 < x1 < 0.7      0.9 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.3 < x1 < 0.7      0 < x2 < 0.3      


2D Testcase 8
Box:  0.3 < x1 < 0.7      0.7 < x2 < 1      
Box:  0.3 < x1 < 0.7      0 < x2 < 0.1      


2D Testcase 9
Box:  0.3 < x1 < 0.7      0.3 < x2 < 0.7      


3D Testcase (corner): 
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0.7 < x2 < 1      0.7 < x3 < 1      
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0.7 < x2 < 1      0 < x3 < 0.1      
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.1      0.7 < x3 < 1      
Box:  0.7 < x1 < 1      0 < x2 < 0.1      0 < x3 < 0.1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0.7 < x2 < 1      0.7 < x3 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0.7 < x2 < 1      0 < x3 < 0.1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0 < x2 < 0.1      0.7 < x3 < 1      
Box:  0 < x1 < 0.1      0 < x2 < 0.1      0 < x3 < 0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand how you specify the boxes by the `bounds` member. Usually, you can specify a box in arbitrary dimension by a "minimum corner" and a "maximum corner". But your `bounds` member seems to have `size() == D`. How do you obtain the minimum and maximum corner from them?

Comment: If ```b``` is a box, then ```b.bounds[d]``` contains the pair {minimum,maximum} in the d'th dimension. So, ```b.bounds[d].first``` and ```b.bounds[d].second``` are the lower and upper bounds, respectively, in the d'th dimension. e.g. ```b.bounds[0]``` holds {x1,x2}, ```b.bounds[1]``` holds{y1,y2}, ```b.bounds[2]``` holds {z1,z2} etc in 3-d. A minimum "corner" would be (in 3 dimensions) ```(b.bounds[0].first, b.bounds[1].first, b.bounds[2].first)```. (I'm not using a data structure like the box model from boost.)

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for claryfying

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to consider cases at all. If you truly want this to generalize easily you need to properly understand the problem domain.

On dimension d a "box" is basically the interior of a region defined by 2 * d coordinates. Or by an origin and d vectors.

- in 1D you have a point and a distance to that point.
- in 2D you have a point and a vertical distance and a horizontal distance.
- in 3D you have a point and 3 vectors in the up forward and left directions...

the intersection of two boxes is itself a box whose coordinates are given by the intersections of each line with each box.

i.e. for each dimension

- Grab the 2 vectors along that dimension for both boxes and their starting coordinates.
- Compute the 4 axis only coordinate values of your 4 points (e.g. only the x values)
- Of those 4 points find the minimum and the maximum.
- Discard those 2. The coordinates you are left with lie inside the intersection.

It should be like 10 lines of code at most.

in more pseudo code:

```
intersections = set()
for i in dimensions
   let c_1 = box1.point[i]
   let c_2 = box1.point[i] + box1.lengths[i]

   let d_1 = box2.point[i]
   let d_2 = box2.point[i] + box2.lengths[i]

   let min, max = find_min_max(c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2)
   let remaining = remove min max from [c_1, c_2, d_1, d_2]

    add remaining to set
```

This will give you the points of the intersection. You then need to convert those points back into a point length representation. But I leave that to you as it is straight forward. Note I am assuming the boxes are axis aligned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see how you compute intersections of boxes, but how does this help to solve the problem? For example, in the first example shown in my picture (on the upper left side), how do you obtain the 4 boxes as an "intersection" of the original box?

Comment: @0xbadf00d For this particular case you can just compute the 4 boxes generated by taking the floating point modulus of the point sin the small box and doing the above for the 4 generated boxes.

Comment: the fmod of the points with respect to what? In 2d the box is described by a point p and a length vector u. How do you compute the boxes from that using fmod?

Comment: In your example the large box represents a torus space. So the coordinates of the small box points can be split into 4 distinct boxes using modulus.

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do this is to compute the modulus transformation of one of the corners, translate your box by the translation that maps the old corner to the new, then do the box intersection I described.

Comment: And do you think this beneficial over the [solution by lastchance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75701525/547231)?

Comment: I think we may actually have converged to the same solution. Glancing over it it seems he did pretty much what I am suggesting.

Comment: I don't really understand how the boxes are specified by the `bounds` member.